# SQLAlchemy: Logical Operators with case statement

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Here is my mssql code snippet

```
SELECT
Sum((Case  When me.status not in ('CLOSED','VOID') and me.pc_cd in ('IK','JM')
Then 1 else 0 end)) as current_cd
from
ccd_pvc me with(nolock)
```

How would i use the **and** operator with case statement if i write the above statement in sqlalchemy.

I have tried doing this but did not work

```
case([and_((ccd_pvc.status.in_(['CLOSED', 'VOID']),ccd_pvc.pc_cd.in_(['IK','JM'])),
literal_column("'greaterthan100'"))])
```

I have searched through the [sqlalchemy documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=case#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.case) but did not find the info on using logical operators with case statement.

The [link](https://gitorious.org/sqlalchemy/mainline/source/ef0245654b6dcbc3977f2aff907adb0c01b30ef5:lib/sqlalchemy/sql/expression.py#L426) has some info on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
ccd_pvc = aliased(CcdPvc, name="me")

expr = func.sum(
    case([(and_(
        ccd_pvc.status.in_(['CLOSED', 'VOID']),
        ccd_pvc.pc_cd.in_(['IK', 'JM'])
    ), 1)], else_=0)
).label("current_cd")

q = session.query(expr)
```